# CSS: huge difference in Chrome & Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, webkit

Just noticed a huge difference in displaying elements with margin in FF and Chrome. That's a link to [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0e29a57q/1/)

In Chrome, everything is okay, while Firefox overlaps `<span>` and `<input>` elements. Also, since the action button is

Any solution for this?

Comment: It's okay for me in Firefox 82.0.3.

Comment: @Ghost It does overlap on each other, using firefx developer edition 82.0b9 (64-bit)

Comment: Mine is 82.0.2 (stable) on Ubuntu and it does overlap on each other

Comment: Ah yes it does, my bad. Didn't notice the margins. Also does on edge.

Comment: your css is not quite right when you look at it.  your input box is set to 100% width.  
and then your box containing them qty-pr also has a limited width.   If you remove the widths from both of these it works fine on firefox and chrome